# Не работает метод ymaps.ready

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В течение дня, через некоторое количество загрузок js api Яндекс карт, перестаёт работать метод *ymaps.ready* и api в принципе. Количество запросов в кабинете разработчика в пределах бесплатного тарифа.
Загружаю api по url: https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=API_KEY&lang=ru_RU

Тестовый вызов не приводит ни к чему.

```
ymaps.ready(() => {console.log('ready')}, () => {console.log('not ready')})
    .then(() => {console.log('res'), () => {console.log('rej')}})
    .catch(() => {console.log('catch')})
```

Comment: на такое смогут ответить только в техподдержке яндекса.

Comment: Всё верно, нужно в поддержку писать с указанием конкретной страницы или рабочим примером, на котором это они смогут воспроизвести ситуацию и сам ключ проверить.